# "Hard disk failure is imminent" warning from HP desktop – is the drive really dying?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bsod, smart

please be patient, I'm disabled (run down by Postal truck on my motorcycle) so I can only Google search things for so long before sitting feels like I got hit by a sledgehammer. Also, I'm on a budget so I can't just solve everything with "buy a new one", disability doesn't pay very well (-;/. I have an HP Win 7 Desktop and I got a blue screen followed by a "hard disk failure is imminent", but I want to verify it's real before I act. It came up 6 weeks ago and I'm still using my PC normally except for 2 things, loading everything is slow (in windows and the web) and my tower is always quiet (the fans are both running but never change speeds as they normally would). I've run check disk and other tests and not gotten any warnings, tests all "negative". 1) Is it possible it's just a virus? I surf many nefarious sites (Pirate Bay downloading movies etc) and 2) Is there a test that will determine if the HDD is actually toast? Thanks my new friends. Oh, and the HDD is not laboring, it's whisper quiet...

Comment: Given your browsing habits, are you running an antivirus program?  If not, download one immediately.  Several major brands have free versions (Avira, AVG) or limited trials (most other brands).  You might even try a rescue disk (such as from Kaspersky) to make sure nothing is on there that would prevent the installation of AV software.  After you're sure you are virus free, then you can start checking the hardware.

Comment: Did you do a chkdsk /R c:  ??  Then look at the number of bad sectors.  The problem is many diagnostic programs cost money, in fact, as much as a new hard drive (2TB) depending on its capacity.

Comment: But note also that ``chkdsk /r`` can take a ***long*** time (I've heard over eight hours), so plan accordingly.

Comment: Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

"Hard disk failure is imminent" is an HP BIOS message saying that the disk has failed one or more [**SMART**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) attributes and is likely to fail soon. You can use [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html) to get SMART data from the drive; post the information here so we can see what precisely is wrong with the drive. (NB: You can hide the drive's serial number in CrystalDiskInfo by selecting **Function** > **Hide Serial Number**).

Take this seriously. **Back up any data on the drive and replace it.** Backup and cloud storage provider Backblaze [found that disks are **very likely to fail soon** if any of these five SMART attributes is nonzero](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/what-smart-stats-indicate-hard-drive-failures/):

- 0x05 Reallocated Sectors Count
- 0xBB Reported Uncorrectable Errors
- 0xBC Command Timeout
- 0xC5 Current Pending Sector Count
- 0xC6 Uncorrectable Sector Count